# Why a wave does not enter a cable? Understanding TDR (Time Domain Reflectometry)

Tags: electromagnetism, cables, wave, transmission-line, waveguide

I have been doing some TDR (Time Domain Reflectometry) measures which involves sending gaussian pulses through a cable and measuring the s11 (reflection) parameter.

In this measure, I could see that from some frequency on, most of the pulse was reflected in the beginning of the cable and it didn't (or it didn't seem to) enter the cable. This reflection happens due to the difference of the impedance of the cable and the impedance of the source but it seemed to be more important at higher frequencies.

The effect of the wave not entering the cable, was also partially because of the higher attenuation at higher frequencies. Anyway, the peak of the reflection in the beginnig was also much bigger in higher frequencies.

So...

Is it because the wave cannot be difracted (or refracted?) into the cable for its small wavelenght?

Or is it because the difference between the impedances of the source and the cable has gotten bigger, so the reflection coefficient has grown bigger? If both impedances depend on frequency, the difference shouldn't grow that much, or what?

25MHz
[image]

250MHz
[image]

1GHz
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details such as frequency range, type of cable (e.g. coax), source impedance, length of the cable?

Comment: Did you keep the source impedance of the pulse constant over the whole range of frequencies?

Comment: I work in a frequency range from aound 25 MHz to 3 GHz and I work with several types of cables, coaxial, low-voltage shielded cables... The response of the coaxial ones is usually better of course, but mainly because de connector is better (N connector). The impedance of the source (a VNA) is 50 ohms everytime.

Comment: Can you include some charts/plots of what your TDR results look like?

Comment: The first one is for 25 MHz, second 250 MHz and the third 1 GHz

Comment: Sorry. I really don't 'get' these tdr plots. What is the -1 to 1 axis?

Comment: What are the units of the X axis?

Comment: Downvote locked it until edits. I would have bumped it back after informative comments, but so it goes.

Comment: downvoted for lack of clarity, graphs, etc. This has the makings of a *great* question.

Comment: The question would be a much better resource for future readers if you left the plots in.

Comment: NB: a TDR is Time Domain Reflectometry. So the x-axis should be TIME ... And it is not intended for "measuring" S11 ..., but VNA can do it. TDR is intended to measure "defaults" of cables (type, length ...)  ... and locate WHERE they are ...

Answer (score 3):

> I have been doing some TDR (Time Domain Reflectometry) measures which involves sending gaussian pulses through a cable and measuring the s11 (reflection) parameter.

But in comments you say the source of your signal is a VNA.

A VNA can not do the measurement you describe. It cannot produce a gaussian pulse.

What it can do is produce sinusoidal stimulus at different frequencies. Then sweep the frequency to obtain the S<sub>11</sub> scattering parameter.

Then it can do some mathematical analysis to tell you what the time domain reflection would look like, assuming the system is linear.

> I could see that from some frequency on, most of the pulse was reflected in the beginning of the cable and it didn't (or it didn't seem to) enter the cable. This reflection happens due to the difference of the impedance of the cable and the impedance of the source but it seemed to be more important at higher frequencies.

If you are seeing a frequency dependent reflection, then something in your system doesn't have consistent behavior across frequencies. Some possibilites are

- Your transmission line is not maintaining its characteristic impedance at high frequencies. It may also become a multimode transmission line at high enough frequencies.
- Your connectors are not ideal at higher frequencies. They may have some excess capacitance or inductance that causes a reflection. Excess shunt capacitance would cause a negative reflection at high frequencies and excess series inductance would cause a positive reflection at high frequencies, when viewed in a TDR. However its possible the parasitics of a connector might not be simple enough to model with a single parasitic element.
- It's unlikely if you're testing with a VNA that the source would not perform consistently across frequencies that it's able to produce. However if you did not calibrate the system correctly (An Open-Short-Load cal is best, but even a Short response cal is probably okay if you don't need perfect accuracy) you could see some issues.

**Edit**

Thanks for including the plots.

What you're seeing is not that the reflection is different at different frequencies, but that the way you are measuring, you are effectively filtering the response with a low pass filter. As you reduce the cut-off frequency of this filter you're smearing out the reflection in time. But you're not adding energy to the reflection, so the peak amplitude has to decrease as the pulse width increases.

If you have a VNA, and you want to see how the reflection depends on frequency, it would be more clear to just plot |S<sub>11</sub>| vs. frequency.

Comment: It is true that the VNA doesn't send diretly the gaussian pulse, but it does an intern calcule in order to produce the same effect. With the VNA you get the H(w) of the cable then this is multiplied by the gaussian in frequency domain (the X(w) signal) and what you get is the Y(w). With an IFFT you get your y(t) which is you TDR refletogram. So do you consider that is has nothing to do with the geometry of the connector? What you are saying is that a parasitic L is created in the connector that rises the impedance of the connector?

Comment: @Xabi, can you share your TDR results? How do you know the reflection happens mostly at high frequencies?

Comment: I don't get why do you say I am filtering the signal. What happenned to the other answer? He was saying that the skin effect may change the impedance of the cable... Is that true? So in your opinion the same proportion of energy is reflected but as the peak in high frequency is thinner it is also higher?

Comment: The guy who did the other answer has a history of abusing the site, so his answers (and accounts) get removed whenever he shows up.

Comment: As for why you are filtering...Your plots don't show signs that the reflection is different at different frequencies. They show that when you change the frequency range of the measurement used (with all that math) to estimate the reflection response, you measure a different result. If there was a selective reflection at, say, 500 MHz, you would see almost no reflection when you measure with 25 MHz bandwidth, and you would see a ringing response when you measure with 1 GHz bandwidth.

Comment: So you think the reflection coefficient is just the same. But the amplitude of the gaussian pulse multiplied in frequency is always the same (one), so I'm sending thinner gaussians of the same heigh everytime. Why should I have a higher response (in the y axis I mean) in hight frequencies? It should be just the same heigh but thinner, shouldn't it?

Comment: This looks like about a 1ft length of unterminated cable. I wonder what the length of the cable is, and how it is terminated.

Comment: @BobbiBennett, In a real TDR, you always see a pulse at t~=0, due to the outgoing pulse being measured by the sensor. I'm not sure if the VNA TDR mode has this same behavior (or simulates it deliberately), or if something else is going on.

Comment: I'm sorry the graphs are cut I cannot show more for privacy reasons, but the figure continues and at the end of the reflectogram there is a peak due to the open circuit of the end. This final peak is smaller with higher frequencies due to attenuation. The peak you see is due to a bad connector, if you use a good one the peaks are much smaller.

Comment: The 1ghz plot has a little bump at t=0, and the big peak a bit after that. That's where I got the guess from. This whole question looks like a mis-interpretation of a very simple behavior, so teasing out details like cable length and axis calibration might solve it.

Comment: This behaviour is independent of the length of the cable beacause it happens everytime not a really good connector is used and with any length. The calibration is made from 1 kHz to 2 GHz and even if I calibrate for the maximal frequency used everytime, the results are the same.

Comment: @BobbiBennett, You're right, if the x-scale is microseconds and the cable is only 30 cm long, then we're not getting real good resoltion of the features.

Comment: The x scale is seconds multiplied by 1E-7

Comment: @Xabi, that's still too big a scale to tell what's going on unless your features are separated by at least 1.5 m or so.

Answer (score 0):

I am [observing similar things with my FDR](http://bit.ly/EchoFDR).  At higher sweep frequencies, impedance discontinuities are more apparent.  I think it's because lower frequencies are more forgiving because the wavelength is much larger than the feature causing the discontinuity.